# How to create complex queries with elixir ets

Tags: caching, erlang, elixir, ets

I have cached a bunch of postcode and lat-long values using erlangs ets functionality.

Picture the following...

```
iex()> :ets.new(:postcode_cache, [:named_table])
:postcode_cache
iex()> :ets.insert(:postcode_cache, [{"OX495NU", "latlongvalue"},{"M320JG", "latlongvalue"}])
true
```

This is similar to the ets table I have created in my application. I want to create a function that only selects entries from the cache where the postcode contains a substring of what a user has entered. Is there any way to do this, and if so, how would I implement this functionality?

(In the future I may like to only select values that are within a certain distance using the lat-long value but that is beyond the scope of this question).

Just for clarity, the table is similar to the following elixir list...

```
iex()> postcode_list = [{"OX495NU","latlong"}, {"M320JG", "latlong"}]
```

The functionality that I would like to replicate with ets is something like this...

```
iex()> Enum.filter(list, fn({postcode, _}) -> if String.contains?(postcode, "OX49") end)
[{"OX495NU", "latlong"}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One cannot invoke arbitrary functions in matches, but here you have a match on hand that can be used with [`:ets.foldl/3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#foldl-3):

```
:ets.foldl(fn
  {<<"0X49", _ :: binary>>, "latlong"} = n, acc -> [n | acc]
  _, acc -> acc
end, [], :named_table)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to understand your answer but cannot get it to work with my example so sorry if I am misunderstanding something.

It looks like you are folding through the ets list and pattern matching on the postcode string with `<<"0X49", _ :: binary>>`, then creating a new list with all cases that match the postcode pattern match. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Binary matches with undetermined byte lengths are not accepted by `:ets.fun2ms`, that’s why.

Comment: Cool that's really good to know thanks (I am pretty new to all this stuff). I think I have an okay understanding of what is going on now but I am still getting an error. I think that the third line of your answer should be `acc -> acc`, not `_ -> acc`. This is giving me an `:ets.safe_fixtable` error. Is there something that I am misunderstanding in your answer?

Comment: Damn, of course, thanks for the sharp eye, fixed. Now it should be correct.